# I am not understanding what has asked to compute of the following exercise.

Tags: calculus, numerical-methods, roots

let $f(x)=(x+2)(x+1)x(x-1)^3(x-2)$.

To which zero of $f$ does the *Bisection method* converges when applied on the interval $[-3,2.5]$

Have i asked to find the root of $f(x)$ ?

Comment: Note that you already know the roots of $f$ as it is factored. And if $f$ has only one root in $[a,b]$, the bisection method will converge to this root. You will reach this situation after a few steps.

Comment: @julien Thank you very much. It is the best answer.

Comment: Did you notice the *answers* given to your question? (See below.) In particular, my answer is basically the same as julien's comment (and preceded it by a few minutes).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you know how to implement the bisection method? *Every* zero of $f$ lies in the initial interval (how can we tell?), but after a few iterations, there will be only one remaining. That is the zero to which the method will converge.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are right. [Bisection method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bisection_method) is a method of finding roots of a function.

Comment: Who is right about what? The OP knows what the Bisection method is -- he has asked three questions about it and shown some of his work.

Comment: you should have known: I am answering means my answer is for the questioner. Otherwise, I would have specified whom my answer was directed to.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid evaluating the actual function repeatedly, note first that the zeros of the function are $$x=-2, -1, 0, 1, 2$$ ($x=1$ is a triple zero)

These are all "trapped" by the original boundaries.  Note also that the function changes sign at **each** zero;  the exponent of  $3$ on the $(x-1)$ term ensures that.  Also, with an odd number of zeros, the function has a different sign at each original boundary.

The first trial is at $$x_1=\frac{-3+2.5}{2}=-0.25$$This "traps" the zeros $-1$ and $-2$ to the left in the interval $(-3, -0.25)$;  the sign of the function is the same at both ends of this sub-interval.

$x_1=-0.25$ traps the other **three** zeros to the right in the interval $(-0.25, 2.5)$;  the function has a different sign at $-0.25$ and $2.5$.  This means that the next trial is at:$$x_2=\frac{-0.25+2.5}{2}=1.125$$This traps two zeros between $-0.25$ and $1.125$;  the function has the same sign at each end of this sub-interval.

$x_2=1.125$ traps the one remaining zero, $2$, in the interval $(1.125, 2.5)$.  This is the zero that will ultimately be determined from the original interval.